# Get latest git tag in Ruby for use with Capifony

Tags: ruby, git, capistrano, capifony

I've followed [this](http://jeremycook.ca/2012/11/04/continuous-deployment-with-symfony2-jenkins-and-capifony/) for several of our projects.  It works wonderfully, except grabbing the latest git tag.  For example, if I have tags 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,  Capifony will try to deploy tag 9 because it sees that as the latest tag using the code provided on that how-to.

How can I change the following line to always get the latest tag?

```
set :branch, `git tag`.split("\n").last
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `git tag` is alphabetical.  How 'bout `git tag | sort -n`?

Alternatively you could perform a numeric sort on the result of the `split` before grabbing the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

`git tag --sort=version:refname` will sort this kind of tag properly.